# How to create Horizontal Scroll View in Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to place `8 Image Views` horizontally in a constraint layout, but the problem is that `2 Image Views` of `200X200` occupies the whole screen horizontally, and the third image is outside the screen.

When i was using normal layout, i put all of these in a `Horizontal Scroll View`.

My Question is do i need to Use Horizontal Scroll View in Constraint Layout as well? If so, then I am again creating Nesting layout here.

Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 2):

Your view hierarchy should be something like this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView>
   <ConstraintLayout>  
      <The 8 image views>
   </ConstraintLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

A constraint layout reduces nesting. This doesn't mean that it can be used in place of scrollable views as well. You can replace the child of a scrollable view from relative/linear layout to a constraint layout like I've done above.

PS: Why are you placing 'eight' image views in the horizontal scroll view?
Try using a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with ImageView item instead.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of HorizontalScrollView with ConstraintLayout.

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    too`enter code here`ls:context="com.zoftino.androidui.ActivityScroll">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button One"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button Two"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button Three"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button Four"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button Five"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></Button>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```